# C Socket: read finish on close in server

Tags: c, sockets

I have a simply program with server and client that comunicate with AF_STREAM socket.
Client will can send multiple request to server, and the server response with a string but I don't know the lenght. The client stops in reading when read return 0 and restarts after the server stops the comunication. I don't understand why.

```
//SEVER
int main(void){
    int idSockServer, idSockClient, clientLen;
    struct sockaddr_in indirizzoClient, indirizzoServer;
    unsigned short richiesta = 0;
    char nomeFile[L_STRING], buffer[L_BUFFER];
    printf("Inizializzaione del server\n");
    idSockServer = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(idSockServer == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Errore socket\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    indirizzoServer.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    indirizzoServer.sin_port = htons(5566);
    indirizzoServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
    if(bind(idSockServer, (struct sockaddr *) &indirizzoServer, sizeof(indirizzoServer))){
        fprintf(stderr, "Errore bind\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(listen(idSockServer, 5) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Errore listen\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while(1){
        printf("[SERVER] Pronto!\n");
        clientLen = sizeof(indirizzoClient);
        idSockClient = accept(idSockServer, (struct sockaddr *) &indirizzoClient, &clientLen);
        if(idSockClient == -1){
            printf("[SERVER] Errore alla connessione\n");
            continue;
        }
        read(idSockClient, &richiesta, L_BUFFER);
        switch(richiesta){
            case 1:
                printf("[SERVER] Richiesta 1 accetata, invio risposta\n");
                //this simulates the variable lenght string
                strcpy(buffer, "un file\n");
                write(idSockClient, buffer, L_BUFFER);
                break;

        }
        sleep(6);
        close(idSockClient);
    }   
}
```

Here the client

```
//CLIENT
int main(void) {
    int sockIdClient, clientLen, file, len;
    char buffer[L_BUFFER], nomeFile[L_STRING];
    struct sockaddr_in indirizzoClient;
    unsigned short scelta, risposta = 0;
    sockIdClient = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockIdClient == -1) {
        perror("Errore creazione socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }//fine if creazione socket
    indirizzoClient.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    indirizzoClient.sin_family = AF_INET;
    indirizzoClient.sin_port = htons(5566);
    if (connect(sockIdClient, (struct sockaddr *) &indirizzoClient, sizeof (indirizzoClient)) == -1) {
        perror("Errore connessione al server");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }//fine connect
    do {
        printf("1) File disponibili\n");
        printf("2) Scarica file\n");
        printf("0) Esci\n");
        printf("Scelta --> ");
        scanf("%hu", &scelta);
        switch (scelta) {
            case 1:
                write(sockIdClient, &scelta, sizeof (unsigned short));
                len = read(sockIdClient, buffer, L_BUFFER);
                while (len > 0) {
                    printf("%s", buffer);
                    printf("%d\n", len);
                    len = read(sockIdClient, buffer, len);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                //This part of code is not managed by Server yet
                write(sockIdClient, &scelta, sizeof (unsigned short));
                read(sockIdClient, &risposta, sizeof (int));
                if (risposta) {
                    printf("Nome file: ");
                    leggiStringa(nomeFile, L_STRING);
                    write(file = sockIdClient, nomeFile, L_STRING);
                    if (open(nomeFile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, "0666") == -1) {
                        perror("Errore apertura del file");
                        close(sockIdClient);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }//fine open
                    len = read(sockIdClient, buffer, L_BUFFER);
                    while (len > 0) {
                        write(file, buffer, L_BUFFER);
                        printf("leggo..\n");
                        len = read(sockIdClient, buffer, len);
                    }
                    close(file);
                } else printf("Il server non ha accetato la richiesta\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Scelta non valida");
        }
    } while (scelta != 0);
    close(sockIdClient);
}
```

Comment: When the server closes the connection, the client gets EOF, which means `read()` returns `0`.

Comment: You should call and read `man read`.

Comment: Why is your server sending the uninitialized `buffer`?

Comment: You can't expect to `write/read` buffer in one go. Also, you don't check some `write` and `read` return values.

Comment: Moreover, if you want to send strings of unknown length between client and server, you will require some kind of protocol. The easiest way is to send length of string first as some integer/unsigned integer of fixed size, so you can expect e.g. 4 bytes which will tell you how long string will be next.

Comment: `int clientLen` should be `socklen_t clientLen`.